# Where to find iOS Simulator on SDK/Xcode4 download?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, ipad

I need to use the iOS Simulator for a iPad website I'm working on.

I have downloaded Xcode4(http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action)

I'm now looking for the iOS Simulator and can't find it anywhere. Do I have to launch it via Xcode if so how?

EDIT:

I'm not seeing any Developer Folder. Someone on the App store said this on a rating of Xcode...

"Is the Developer folder put somewhere other than the top level of the hard drive?"

Comment: first of all, please install the downloaded image... Once you install it with default options, a `Developer` folder will be reated in your root directory and all software will be installed there.

Comment: I have opened the application called 'Install Xcode'. After it was finished I still had no Developer folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the spotlight search for "iOS Simulator" - once it is found, launch it.
It'll probably open as an iPhone simulator so select from simulators' menu "Hardware -> Device -> iPad"

Comment: I just went to the App Store and clicked install Xcode. Apple's website said the SDK was included in Xcode.

Comment: In Terminal, try executing this: "open -a /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app"

Comment: I get back:  "FSPathMakeRef(/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app) failed with error -43."

Comment: So you're able to launch Xcode or not? If the Xcode is installed on you Mac, try with spotlight, or open it via terminal.

Comment: Turns the SDK wasn't installed. I thought it was because of a previous version of Xcode was on the computer, as well as the App Store saying it was installed but you must go through another installation. Open 'Install Xcode' via spotlight.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to launch it is via Xcode, running an application you’ve just built. If you want to open it manually, though—for testing a website or whatever—it’s in `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/`.

Comment: Are you on OS Lion? I'm looking in my user folder and there is no Developer Folder

Comment: User folders don't start with / but with ~ ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found mine here:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk

Could be they moved it in the latest version of Xcode - I'm running 4.5.2.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that you can add other versions of the simulator by opening Xcode, clicking on Xcode, Preferences ..., Downloads, and then clicking Install on the simulator(s) of your choice.

Comment: I think they moved the tools inside the Application bundle starting with Xcode 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the XCode4 package from App Store application in your Mac. it must have the Simulator application and you can find it in > `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/`.

Comment: Did you have an old version of Xcode before you downloaded it from the App store?